# Compile debug code in or out in Java

Tags: java, compilation

I would like to be able to have my debug code (verbose logging, etc) compiled out when I make a production release, but compiled in for debugging.

I understand that if I branch on a constant, the compiler will remove the branch, which is what I want. So I have a class:

```
class Debug {
  public static final boolean ON=true;
}
```

and my debug code is inside a branch like this:

```
if (Debug.ON) {
    // Verbose / expensive logging goes here
}
```

My question is, how do I arrange for Debug.ON to be set to true or false at compile time, short of actually editing the source file?

EDIT: Note that I am not concerned with controlling whether log output appears or not - I am using java.util.Logging and it can take care of that. I am more concerned with compiling out any expensive code that is preparing log messages which will never get output, or taking measurements that are not needed in production mode.

I guess I could have an ant target that makes the source file from a template or something, but it seems like a hack. In C++ I'd be able to define a pre-processor symbol which I could pass in with -D - is there any Java equivalent? Or some other better way?

Comment: You *really* want to use logj4 or its brethren.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  With this, when you build for production you use one logging config file, when you run in development, you use another.

Comment: More specifically, use slf4j (or log4j2); you specify your log messages as patterns, and they don't even get evaluated unless you have that particular logging turned on. You're going to add more bugs doing this than you'll offset with time or performance gains.

Comment: What happens where there is significant computation required to prepare the log message to start with? For example, I have a large buffer full of binary data I want to log in hex format, I need to convert it to hex before even invoking the logging framework. I want to avoid that overhead in a production environment.

Comment: BTW, should have mentioned at the start, I am currently using java.util.Logging to do the actual logging. I am aware that there are several other frameworks that are probably better, but the main thing I am trying to address is compiling out expensive code in production environments, not controlling whether logging will appear.

Comment: Read external file or put it into properties. Ugly, but works.

Comment: @harmic You can use `isLoggable` as jackrabbit suggests, but I'd also suggest writing a thin wrapper class with a reasonable `toString()` if the buffer doesn't already have one; it'll be helpful for a number of applications, and it's essentially a lazy evaluator for log or debug output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is have two Jars or class files.

The one contains the Debug class with ON = true and the other ON = false.

Then when you compile depending on what debug state you want you include the DEBUG on class/jar file or the DEBUG off class/jar file.

Comment: Thanks! I had thought of doing something like this, but was hoping for a more elegant solution. But it seems Java does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Wiles' answer is probably the most straightforward way to do exactly what you ask. However, all of the popular logging frameworks let you query whether a logger is configured to actually output anything at a specific logging level.

For `java.util.logging` you would use [`isLoggable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#isLoggable%28java.util.logging.Level%29). While this is not a compile time check, it should be fairly cheap compared to logging something expensive to compute.