# javac equivalent of "-D"?

Tags: java, c++

Is there a way to give the java compiler some kind of variable that is accessible to the running java code?
In C/C++ I can give the compile `-DKEY=VALUE` and that would cause the preprocessor to have a `#define` for KEY equals to VALUE. I can then check this value in compile time to effect what code is being compiled.
I found `java`'s -D, but that puts values give the the `java` command line in `System.getProperty()`. I want an argument give in compile time, not invocation time.

Comment: Java doesn't have a C preprocessor, and it doesn't have anything like `#define`.

Comment: @khelwood did I imply that it does?

Comment: You can't, as java doesn't have a preprocessor. You'll be able to use something like define with external tools (like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)).

Comment: "The running java code"? The code that is being compiled is not running at compile time.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't think it is possible to pass instructions to the preprocessor, because the Java compiler does not have anything like the C preprocessor.

Comment: as far as I know, you can put any type of properties within your code, then you can compile the code and have desired properties...

Comment: out of curiosity. what is the benefit of compile time availability of the flag?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Java doesn't have a built-in preprocessor (at least not with macro support), as others have noted. However, there's nothing to stop you from running one manually - even the C pre-processor, if you so wished.

Comment: I had a similar requirement (or at least similar end goal) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136624/compile-debug-code-in-or-out-in-java). I never got any solution I really liked.

Comment: You could just run the java source through the C preprocessor using `gcc -E` or equivalent before compiling it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With java annotations it is possible to generate additional code on the fly, which can be configured on command line. It allow to produce more source code, configuration files, xml files, ... The main limitation is that you are allowed only to (re)generate new source files, you cannot modify existing ones.

Below is a short tutorial on how to allow from javac command specify parameters which will be visible in Java code. How usefull is that? Ie. you could specify a boolean option which would disable some parts of code, I am preety sure this parts of code could be removed using tools like proguard - or even optimized out by javac. Other uses is to specify new version number. Those use cases are mostly what c++ marcros are used for.

So, you need :

- a dummy annotation class which will allow processor to run. It should be specified only once in your application.
- a processor class which will run for above dummy annotation, and generate options class. It will also read options from javac command line.
- a dummy Main class for testing purposes.

You will have to also compile your processor file before compiling Main class. This of course is done only when processor class is modified. All the three files are at the bottom. Now the compilation looks as follows (I am on windows):

Compile processor:

```
javac .\com\example\ConfigWritterAnnotationProcessor.java
```

Then Main.java with additional parameters to processor:

```
javac -processor com.example.ConfigWritterAnnotationProcessor -AtextToPrint="Hello World!" -AenablePrint=true ./com/example/Main.java
```

And thats all, now you may run Main.class and it will use Options class generated during compilation with above parameters set. It will look as follows:

```
package com.example;
public class Options {
    public static final String textToPrint = "Hello World!";
    public static final boolean enablePrint = true;
}
```

---

ProcessorStarterAnnotation.java

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface ProcessorStarterAnnotation {
}
```

Main.java

```
package com.example;

@ProcessorStarterAnnotation
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      if ( com.example.Options.enablePrint ) {
        System.out.println(com.example.Options.textToPrint);
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Print disabled");
      }
    }
}
```

ConfigWritterAnnotationProcessor.java

```
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.ProcessorStarterAnnotation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
@SupportedOptions({"textToPrint", "enablePrint"})
public class ConfigWritterAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
  private Map<String,String> options;

  @Override
  public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
    super.init(processingEnv);
    options = processingEnv.getOptions();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                         RoundEnvironment currentRound) {

    if (!currentRound.processingOver()) {
      // This for-s are because processor is also run on newly created Options class.
      for (TypeElement te : annotations) {
        for (Element e : currentRound.getElementsAnnotatedWith(te)) {
          try {
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "Creating com.example.Options");
            JavaFileObject javaFile = processingEnv.getFiler().createSourceFile("com.example.Options");
            Writer w = javaFile.openWriter();
            try {
              PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(w);
              pw.println("package com.example;");
              pw.println("public class Options {");
              pw.println("    public static final String textToPrint = \"" + options.get("textToPrint") + "\";");
              pw.println("    public static final boolean enablePrint = " + options.get("enablePrint") + ";");
              pw.println("}");
              pw.flush();
            } finally {
              w.close();
            }
          } catch (IOException x) {
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                x.toString());
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using an annotation class is convenient, but you don't have to create one (or use any annotations at all) just to trigger pluggable source code processing. Returning a wildcard (`*`) from [getSupportedAnnotationTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html#getSupportedAnnotationTypes--) will cause processor to be run even if there is absolutely no annotations in source code. Then use [Types#getTypeElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#getTypeElement-java.lang.CharSequence-) to locate stuff by name.

Comment: Also note that adding `-processor` argument is not necessary to make processors run. They are automatically discovered as long as one adds appropriate [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)-compatible text file to the jar and places it on compilation classpath.

Answer (score 12):

`javac` has the

```
-Akey[=value]
```

commandline option to pass information to [annotation processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation#Processing).

Comment: What's an annotation processor?

Comment: @shoosh the Java version of a C++ preprocessor. Added a link in the answer

Comment: providing just a link without any explanation on how to actually do it is not a proper answer to the question. I've been reading about annotation for the better part of an hour and I still can't figure it out. If you can answer the question, do so.

Comment: I guess one project to note is AspectJ where annotations are used to match aspects with functions. for instance the execute around aspect. poke around in their aspect weaver to see how they achieve compile time reorganizing of source code.

Comment: @Ferrybig see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like this in Java. Compile time constants must be declared in source code, and as far as I know, there is no pre-processor.

BTW, you could use flags given to `java` command line (-D args) to initialize java constants at runtime, that would mimic what you are looking for.

Ex:

```
class Foo {
    private static final String BAR;
    static {
        String foobar = System.getProperty("foo.bar");
        if(foobar != null && foobar.length()>0) {
            BAR = foobar;
        } else {
            BAR = "somedefaultvalue";
        }
    }
}
```

Invoke with `java Xxx -Dfoo.bar=foobar`

Answer (score 1):

As there is no notion of preprocessing in Java, a solution is to design your own.

One may think of using a standard C preprocessor or a custom-made one and compile the preprocessed output, but this has the disadvantage of duplicating the files, so that the project will become more complex, and the support from the development environment will degrade (like ability to jump to a syntax error).

My suggestion is to use annotations via comments that will guide a custom preprocessor and let it do substitutions before compiling.

For example,

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int nDisks = 3;
      doTowers(nDisks, 'A', 'B', 'C');
   }
```

would become

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int nDisks = /*@NDISKS*/ 3 /**/;
      doTowers(nDisks, 'A', 'B', 'C');
   }
```

Then your preprocessor would have a definition file such as

```
NDISKS 5
```

turning the code in

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int nDisks = /*@NDISKS*/ 5 /**/;
      doTowers(nDisks, 'A', 'B', 'C');
   }
```

Similarly, you can emulate conditional code compilation with

```
     doTowers(topN - 1, from, to, inter);
     /*!PRINT*/
     System.out.println("Disk "
     + topN + " from " + from + " to " + to);
     /**/
     doTowers(topN - 1, inter, from, to);
```

which could be turned by the preprocessor (with a definition like `PRINT OFF`) into

```
     doTowers(topN - 1, from, to, inter);
     /*!PRINT
     System.out.println("Disk "
     + topN + " from " + from + " to " + to);
     */
     doTowers(topN - 1, inter, from, to);
```

You can use alternative syntaxes, but the main ideas are

- that the annotated code remains compilable,
- that the preprocessor substitutions are reversible.

Answer (score 0):

It would be against the design of the language to have it that way. What `-DKEY=VALUE` does is that it actually replaces `KEY` with `VALUE` in the source during preprocessor in C/C++.

Java does not have a preprocessor so that's mechanism is not available. If you want something "equivalent" you have to question what you mean by that. By not preprocessing the source it wouldn't be really equivalent.

If you on the other hand would like it to mean to set the value of the symbol `KEY` to the value `VALUE` you'd run into the problem that you would need to declare the symbol `KEY` anyway to determine it's type. In this case it would only be yet another constant/variable with the constraints that implies.

This means that even with such a feature it would not actually alter the generated code and you would hardly be better of than defining the value att launch time. That's why supplying the parameter via `java` would be the way to go.